# Laravel operations returns no error message

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am trying to log back in to my laravel 5.4 application.

Thew weird thing is that it returns no error messages after I hit the login button and it loads.

it just comes back blank. I am suspecting that there is no session taking place that is why. I switched my sessions driver to database and ran the migration, still nothing.

Also every other route seems to redirect me back to the login page

I have tried and searched a lot. I'd appreciate it if someone knows where in the app I can start looking or what could be the cause

Comment: What does it load? Can you give more information about the whole process?

Comment: Have you checked the laravel.log? Are you running over apache? Check the error.log as well

Comment: enable error reporting and check again.